# Python, how to make program sort title words and normal words?

Tags: python, list

I need to write a program that would ask for a random sentence, for example: "This is a Sentence."

And it would print out like this:

```
Title words: This, Sentence
Words: is, a
```

How do I write such a program? I started and I tried making the start and the end but not sure I am going the right way. So far I have this:

```
while True:
    sentence = ("Please enter a sentence:")
    if sentence.title() == True:


for i in range (len(tword)):
    print ("Title words: ", tword[i])
    print ("Words: ", words[i])
```

Could anyone give me hints or tips?

Comment: Define what you mean by "title" word. Is it a word that starts with an uppercase letter followed by only lowercase letters?

Comment: In that case, it should be [word for word in statement.split() if word[0].isupper() ]

Comment: @martineau Title word as in. A word just starts with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `istitle` method

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
words = []
title = []
for i in sentence.split():
    if i.istitle():
        title.append(i)
    else:
        words.append(i)

>>>print('title words:',",".join(title))
title words: This,Sentence

>>>print('words:',",".join(words))
words: is,a
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
>>> my_sentence = "Hello how are you, hello World"
>>> import re
>>> my_sentence = "Hello how are you, hello World"
>>> my_words = re.findall("\w+", my_sentence)     #This will find all words
>>> my_words
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'hello', 'World']
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for x in my_words:
...     if x[0].isupper():  # check for if words start with uppercase or not
...         my_dict['title'] = my_dict.get("title", []) + [x]
...     else:
...         my_dict['word'] = my_dict.get("word", []) + [x]
...
>>> my_dict
{'word': ['how', 'are', 'you', 'hello'], 'title': ['Hello', 'World']}
```

your Desired Output:

```
>>> print "Title: {}\nWord: {}".format(", ".join(my_dict['title']), ", ".join(my_dict['word']))
Title: Hello, World
Word: how, are, you, hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
title_array = [word for word in sentence.split() if word.istitle()]
```

To strip it of from other symbols, more precisely,

```
title_array = [''.join([c for c in word if c.isalnum()]) for word in sentence.split() if word.istitle()]
```

With regex,

```
[''.join([c for c in word if c.isalnum()]) for word in re.split('\W+', sentence) if word.istitle()]
```

Comment: Will have to use regex in that case.

Comment: If you want some more functionality, to split, please read, https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would use using your definition of a title word:

```
import re

sentence = "This is a Sentence."
titles, words = [], []
for word in re.findall("\w+", sentence):
    [words, titles][word[0].isupper()].append(word)

print("Title: {}\nWord: {}".format(", ".join(titles), ", ".join(words)))
```

Output:

```
Title: This, Sentence
Word: is, a
```